# Pandas create column woth all row values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with 2 columns: `id` and `description`

`pd.DataFrame({'id':[1, 2], 'description': ['foo', 'bar']})`

```
+----+-------------+
| id | description |
+----+-------------+
| 1  | foo         |
+----+-------------+
| 2  | bar         |
+----+-------------+
```

What I want to obtain is a data frame in the following form:

```
+------+------+---------------+---------------+
| id_1 | id_2 | description_1 | description_2 |
+------+------+---------------+---------------+
| 1    | 2    | foo           | bar           |
+------+------+---------------+---------------+
```

I have tried using `pivot` together with `groupby` but I cannot rename the columns as I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for reshape with [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose for one row `DataFrame` and last flatten `MultiIndex` with add `1` to second level by `f-string`s:

```
df = df.unstack().to_frame().T
df.columns = [f'{a}_{b + 1}' for a,b in df.columns]
print (df)
  id_1 id_2 description_1 description_2
0    1    2           foo           bar
```

Comment: Thanks @jezrael! I remember you already helped in the past.